# creating application bundle of with Jar files of java for Mac OS X?

Tags: java, macos, bundle, executable-jar

I have written a small game program using Swing, which is organized into packages. I have been struggling to create a `game.app` with hardly any success. I am following  [This link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/packagingAppsForMac.html) and I could not even pass step 1.

first I did `jar cvf HangManProject.jar *` while on the top-level directory.

2. After this, to create the `build.xml`, I right clicked the project folder and generated ant files as shown here. you can notice my `HangManProject.jar` sitting there from previous step.[image]
3. After this step, I have build.xml created and available on my top-level directory (same location as HangManProject.jar).
4. Now I tried `ant jar` as suggested by above link to create dist/HangManProject.jar. but I get the below error message:

   Buildfile: /Users/Tom/Documents/workspace/HangManProject/build.xml

   BUILD FAILED
   Target "jar" does not exist in the project "HangManProject".

As you can see from the image, the HangManProject.jar exist in the same directory. I do not understand why this error pops up.

I also tried `ant -verbose` (without actually knowing what it does) and I get it to work successful

```
build:

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 2 seconds
```

I dont know if `ant -verbose` is helpful in anyway, but I guess I have to get `ant jar` working (step 3) before I proceed to next step in the link above. kindly give me your suggestions.

EDIT:
Here is my `build.xml` that was autogenerated by Eclipse

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!-- WARNING: Eclipse auto-generated file.
              Any modifications will be overwritten.
              To include a user specific buildfile here, simply create one in the same
              directory with the processing instruction <?eclipse.ant.import?>
              as the first entry and export the buildfile again. -->
<project basedir="." default="build" name="HangManProject">
    <property environment="env"/>
    <property name="ECLIPSE_HOME" value="../../../Downloads/eclipse"/>
    <property name="debuglevel" value="source,lines,vars"/>
    <property name="target" value="1.7"/>
    <property name="source" value="1.7"/>
    <path id="JUnit 4.libraryclasspath">
        <pathelement location="${ECLIPSE_HOME}/plugins/org.junit_4.11.0.v201303080030/junit.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="${ECLIPSE_HOME}/plugins/org.hamcrest.core_1.3.0.v201303031735.jar"/>
    </path>
    <path id="HangManProject.classpath">
        <pathelement location="bin"/>
        <path refid="JUnit 4.libraryclasspath"/>
    </path>
    <target name="init">
        <mkdir dir="bin"/>
        <copy includeemptydirs="false" todir="bin">
            <fileset dir="src">
                <exclude name="**/*.launch"/>
                <exclude name="**/*.java"/>
            </fileset>
        </copy>
    </target>
    <target name="clean">
        <delete dir="bin"/>
    </target>
    <target depends="clean" name="cleanall"/>
    <target depends="build-subprojects,build-project" name="build"/>
    <target name="build-subprojects"/>
    <target depends="init" name="build-project">
        <echo message="${ant.project.name}: ${ant.file}"/>
        <javac debug="true" debuglevel="${debuglevel}" destdir="bin" includeantruntime="false" source="${source}" target="${target}">
            <src path="src"/>
            <classpath refid="HangManProject.classpath"/>
        </javac>
    </target>
    <target description="Build all projects which reference this project. Useful to propagate changes." name="build-refprojects"/>
    <target description="copy Eclipse compiler jars to ant lib directory" name="init-eclipse-compiler">
        <copy todir="${ant.library.dir}">
            <fileset dir="${ECLIPSE_HOME}/plugins" includes="org.eclipse.jdt.core_*.jar"/>
        </copy>
        <unzip dest="${ant.library.dir}">
            <patternset includes="jdtCompilerAdapter.jar"/>
            <fileset dir="${ECLIPSE_HOME}/plugins" includes="org.eclipse.jdt.core_*.jar"/>
        </unzip>
    </target>
    <target description="compile project with Eclipse compiler" name="build-eclipse-compiler">
        <property name="build.compiler" value="org.eclipse.jdt.core.JDTCompilerAdapter"/>
        <antcall target="build"/>
    </target>
</project>
```

Comment: Could you post your build.xml? Looks like it doesn't have "jar" target

Comment: @dimoniy: I pasted the build.xml in the edit above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create a "target" in the build.xml file to tell ant how to create the jar (what files to include etc).

See this  [ant tutorial](http://ant.apache.org/manual/tutorial-HelloWorldWithAnt.html) for information on how to do that.

but it will look something like this:

EDIT: now that you pasted your build.xml I added the depends attribute.

```
<target name="jar" depends = "build">
    <jar destfile="HangManProject.jar" >
        <fileset dir="bin"/>    

    </jar>
</target>
```

Although you have to be careful, the build.xml says that eclipse autogenerates this file and any modifications will be overwritten (I assume if you ever change build settings/classpath etc).

Comment: I have pasted my build.xml above

Comment: Thanks for the reply, now I get this error `BUILD FAILED
/Users/Tom/Documents/workspace/HangManProject/build.xml:58: jar doesn't support the "depends" attribute

Total time: 2 seconds`

Comment: That worked, Thanks, but this was supposed to create dist/HangManProject.jar but no such thing happened. The log was 'BUILD SUCCESSFUL`. This link http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/packagingAppsForMac.html indicates a `dist` directory will be created..can you tell me why this did not happen?

Comment: You have to tell ant where to put the jar.  change to `<jar destfile = "dist/HangManProject.jar">`.  Not sure if the dist dir is automatically created, if not, need to explicitly make the dir using mkdir task before you create your new jar file.